# How would I use the header command in the Cloud 9 IDE to redirect someone after their forms are validated?

Tags: php, forms, redirect, cloud9-ide

I am using the Cloud 9 IDE and I had created the registration page would like to redirect the user once they submit their registration credentials. I am trying to do this by using the header method in PHP. However, I don't know if I can use this or would I have to work around it due to the URL they provide you with for your website. For example, the URL would be, "https://example-user.c9users.io/register.php" and the header I am trying to use is:

header("Location:https://vomica-porixify.c9users.io/home.php");

The main problem is that it won't work and I can't figure out why. I don't know if this due to the links you are given or if my registration page is broken.

Here is register.php

```
<?php

    $pageTitle = "Sign Up";
    $section = "signing";

?>

<?php include 'INC/header.php'; ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3"></div>

        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="page-header">

                        <h3 class="text-center"> Register </h3>

                    </div>

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" acion="process.php" method="post">

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="inputUser" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Username </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-10">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                <span class="input-group-addon">

                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </span>

                                </span>

                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUser" placeholder="Username"> 

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> E-Mail </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-10">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <span class="input-group-addon">

                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"> </span>

                                    </span>

                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="E-Mail">

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Password </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-10">

                                <div class="input-group">

                                    <span class="input-group-addon">

                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"> </span>

                                    </span>

                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"> 

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Register </button>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"> User Login </button>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <?php include 'INC/redirect.php' ?>

                    </form>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>

    </div>

<?php include 'INC/footer.php' ?>
```

and here is my redirect.php

```
<?php $pageTitle = "Redirected"; ?>

<?php include 'INC/header.php' ?>

<?php 

    if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {

        // Fetches variables from the form
        $username = $_GET['inputUser'];
        $email = $_GET['inputEmail'];
        $password = $_GET['inputPassword'];

        if(inputUser !='' && inputEmail !='' && inputPassword !='')
        {

            // Redirects to the page
            header("Location:https://vomica-porixify.c9users.io/home.php");

        } else {
            ?> <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo 'Please fill out all the fields!'; ?> </div> <?php
        }

    }

?>

<?php include 'INC/footer.php' ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use header() you should remember that:

> header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

In your code, when you submit the form, there is a post request to call your process.php file, you can write some register code here and user header() to redirect:

```
//process.php

// Register code
...

// Redirect    
header("Location: http://www.example.com/home");
// Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect.
exit;
```

Comment: I am so sorry I accidentally included the same file twice, let me fix that real quick!